# Google Cloud Messagging New Version With API 8

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I can't understand if is it possible to use new Google Cloud Messagging with API 8. I only found examples with the previous GCM library. And in [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) I did not find an explanation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Some devices are having problems, but Google are working on fixing those problems. 
My device had API 8 and the new Google Cloud Messaging worked.

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269607/google-cloud-messaging-register-authentication-failed/19282024#19282024) which contains some relevant discussion. Basically, it suggests to fallback to the deprecated library on Froyo/Gingerbread devices only if the new Google Cloud Messaging doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so can you say to me if is there a good tutorial dedicated on the new Google Cloud Messagging?

Comment: @v1sc3rr4k You're welcome. Why don't you use the official [Demo App](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/)? That's all you need for the client side. For the server side you don't have to change anything if you keep using the GCM HTTP interface.